# getting timestamp of tweets with Twython

Tags: api, twitter, timestamp, tweets, twython

I can't find this information anywhere, even if it seems to me a pretty simple task. However no methods nor threads appeared to me while crawling for answers on the web/docs

I'm using Twython to extract tweets, and I need the timestamps or even just the day at which it was posted. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Twython does is wrap the [Twitter API, so look at that documentation.](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline)

Here is an example:

```
from twython import Twython
twitter = Twython()
timeline = twitter.getUserTimeline(screen_name="handle")
for tweet in timeline:
    print(tweet['created_at'])
```

Comment: oh my god it was that simple. EDIT: sorry for the dumbness, I'm used to data analysis programming but mostly in science so I have some problems in understanding how these IT things work!